# Remove substring from text returned by function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function that returns text but I need to remove a specific substring from the returned text. I've tried a bunch of variations on suggestions I found through stackoverflow but none have worked so far. Any advice?

```
<div id="textfunction">
  <script>
    $().ready(function() {
    console.log($("#textfunction")
        .load("https://example.com/").text().replace("substring",""))}
    );
  </script>
</div>
```

I'd like to get: "Returned text: ." Instead, I'm getting: "Returned text: substring."

Comment: You need to [set the text](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) in addition to getting it as you are now.

Comment: try text(replace("substring",""))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the text, you need to put it into the text function `text("like this")`

```
console.log($("#textfunction").load("https://example.com/").text(replace("substring","")));
```

Will return the text replaced.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I tried them out but my code still won't replace the text for some reason. Is it possible that the text from "https://example.com/" isn't being loaded as standard strings of chars and that "replace" therefore can't find the substring that I want to remove? One other thing: The text has an extra pair of quotation marks on either side that I'd like to remove. I added a ".slice(1,-1)" to get rid of them (I tried but inside the ".text()" and tacked on after the ".text()"). But that didn't work. Am I going about that wrong?

Comment: console.log the example.com and see what is the result. like this: console.log($("#textfunction").load("https://example.com/").text());

Comment: Thanks Evik and @weegee. When I do that, it loads a couple lines of text with double quotes around the entire chunk of text. So the raw html that results after loading looks like this: <div id="textfunction">"""<p>Line 1 from example.com.</p><p></p><p>Line 2 from example.com.</p>"""</div>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a replacement in a chain, this is the right way to do that.

`const cadena = "hola subcadena";
cadena.replace(/subcadena/g, '').trim("")`